# Array Manipulation - Move items up and Add Similar in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So, I am having to do some complicated Array manipulation and am having some difficulty. Thought i might ask you guys for help.

Anyhow, What i am trying to do is basically the following.
Let's say i have an array of numbers, with zeroes peppered. So, What i wanna do is move all elements up to the top of the array and therefore, fill the elements with zereos in them.

I'll use an example to explain ;
Let's say the array is : `{4,4,0,2,0,2}`

What i wanna do is : `{4,4,2,2,0,0}`

So, all the numbers are in one area basically and sorted.
Now, the second thing i wanna do is add all similar numbers, so if we continue with the above example : `{8,4,0,0,0,0}`

Now, what i have tried to is basically run through the whole loop and move the next item back when i see a zero and replace that with a zero but that is leading to some issues.

Some suggestions would be awesome. Thansk

Edit :

I figured out how to do the sorting etc and a little bit of the addition , Here is what i have. Please let me know if you suggestions to make it better.

```
for(int j = 0; j < row.length ; j++){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < row.length ; i++){
            if(row[i] == 0){
                    row[i] = row[i+1];
                    row[i+1] = 0;
            } else if(row[i] == row[i+1] ){
                    row[i] = row[i+1] + row[i];
                    row[i+1] = 0;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

However, the sorting is all fine but there is a slight issue with the addition of similar elements.
So, If we something like `{2,2,2,2,0,0}` after sorting then my addition part will do this : `{8,0,0,0,0,0}` which isn't what i want. What it should be is `{4,4,0,0,0,0}`

Comment: Is it like 2048 or not ? That is, with the array {2,4,2,0,4}, should it produce {8,4,0,0,0} or {2,4,2,4,0} ? Or something else ?

Comment: Well. For a Array like {2,4,2,0,4}, it should be producing {2,4,2,4,0}. That is why ordering is necessary.
Also, i just noticed. It is basically like 2048. Had no idea. Maybe i'll go look at someone's recreation of it. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do that is to split the work in two parts: Combine pairs, and push elements left. About the order of operations:

```
pushLeft then combine
Orignal array:  {4,2,0,2,0,4}
After pushLeft: {4,2,2,4,0,0}
After combine:  {4,4,4,0,0,0}
```

With this order, you have to take care of the holes you create while combining values.

```
combine then pushLeft
Orignal array:  {4,2,0,2,0,4}
After combine:  {4,4,0,0,0,4}
After pushLeft: {4,4,4,0,0,0}
```

Those can be implemented using a simple loop for each function. There is also the possibility to do it all in a single loop (combining and pushing left), but it is more tricky.

My code is below (2nd method), but you may want to give it a try yourself before:

```
public static int[] goLeft(int[] a) {
    int[] arr = a.clone();
    for (int j = 0, i = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[j] != 0) {
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            if (i++ != j) arr[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

public static int[] combine(int[] a) {
    int[] arr = a.clone();
    for (int j = 1, i = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0 && arr[j] != 0) {
            i = j;
        } else if (arr[j] != 0 && i != j) {
            if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
                arr[i] *= 2;
                arr[j] = 0;
                i = j;
            } else {
                i = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a1 = new int[] {4,2,0,2,4};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Main.goLeft(Main.combine(a1))));
    // [4, 4, 4, 0, 0]
}
```